# How to declare and get array value

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell, first time using it.

I have declared an array and use array value but using below code, I am not able to retrieve the array value...Any idea what I am missing here?

Just FYI.. I am executing script in ADOBE ILLUSTRATOR and for testing I am using 3 here in condition (for loop)... will use `$array` later

```
$array = "a.jpg","b.jpg","c.jpg";

for ($i=1; $i-le=3; $i++)  
{
    $.writeln("This is line number " + $array[$i]);
    var targetFileName =  $array[$i]+'.png';
    $.writeln(targetFileName);
}
```

I tried `$array[$i].toString()` as well but still not getting values... I am getting `0`

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance to all for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *`for ($i=1; $i-le=3; $i++)`*

The condition in the above line doesn't have a valid comparison operator. Change that to

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 3; $i++)
```

if you want the loop to terminate after 3 cycles.

---

> *`$.writeln("This is line number " + $array[$i]);`*
>   *`var targetFileName =  $array[$i]+'.png';`*
>   *`$.writeln(targetFileName);`*

This is not valid PowerShell. Looks more like JavaScript to me. In PowerShell it should probably look like this:

```
Write-Output "This is line number $i"
$targetFileName = $array[$i] + '.png'
Write-Output $targetFileName
```

or shorter

```
"This is line number $i"
$array[$i] + '.png'
```

Note that PowerShell arrays are zero-based, so the last iteration (`$array[3]`) will return `$null` instead of an element from the array. If you want to iterate over the elements of the array you should change your loop to this:

```
for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.Length; $i++) {
  "This is line number $($i+1)"
  $array[$i] + '.png'
}
```

or (better) pipe your array into a `foreach` loop:

```
$i = 0
$array | % {
  "This is line number " + ++$i
  $_ + '.png'
}
```